# Lotka-Volterra equations mistake

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem with the Lotka-Volterra equations themselves. I believe that they might be wrong. Here is my reasoning - I would appreciate it if someone could find a flaw  in it!

The equations are generally of the form, as quoted from "A Modern Introduction to Differential Equations 2nd edition by Henry Ricardo":

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = a_1x-a_2xy, \frac{dy}{dt}=-b_1y+b_2xy$$

**My issue:** The $xy$ terms represent the number of possible interactions between two species. However, they only represent the number of possible *one-on-one* interactions between the two species. In order to account for *all* the possible interactions, such as $(x-1)$ predators acting on $2$ preys, shouldn't we arrive at $$\sum_{k=1}^x\sum_{j=1}^y {x \choose k}{y \choose j} = (2^x-1)(2^y-1)$$ and thus $$\frac{dx}{dt} = a_1x-a_2(2^x-1)(2^y-1), \frac{dy}{dt}=-b_1y+b_2(2^x-1)(2^y-1)?$$

Doesn't this make the number of interactions proportional not to the product of the number of predators and prey, but to their exponentiation?

Comment: Read the third Para of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equation#History

Comment: Hi Amzoti, I read the third para and looked up the sources: Arditi-Ginzburg model. But I didn't really understand it. Could you clarify your intent?

Comment: Well, they proved the LV model is flawed big time. They came up with a better model. So, if you are going to spend time with a model, use theirs and spend your time on that. See this accessible write up http://life.bio.sunysb.edu/ee/ginzburglab/Review%20of%20Arditi%20&%20Ginzburg%202012%20in%20Science.pdf. Also see: http://www.amazon.ca/How-Species-Interact-Altering-Standard/dp/0199913838 Regards

Comment: Ok thanks, but this still doesn't answer me if my equations make sense?

Comment: "I have a problem with the Lotka-Volterra equations themselves. I believe that they might be wrong." These are a hell of a pair of sentences to open a post/talk/paper/whatever... Of course what comes next might be somewhat delicate to justify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially all differential equation models in biological science are "wrong" in the sense that they are only approximations.  Reality is much too complicated to express in a few simple equations.  The best you can hope for is that your
equations capture the main features of the actual situation in a limited range
of values of the variables.